# file.exists() unexpectedly returns false

Tags: java, linux

So I have somthing like this:

```
File testFile = new File("/opt/tester/etc/test.properties");
if(!testFile.exists()){
   System.exit(0) }
```

it always exits, looking at the debugger I see that the file was created with a 'path' property of "\opt\tester\etc\test.properties" and a 'prefixLength' of 1

the file exists on the system, I can do an 'ls' and a 'file' commands on it and it works fine,
upon reading about permissions etc I changed the properties of the file to this:

```
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 475 Jun 18 14:11 /opt/tester/etc/test.properties
```

before:

```
 -rw-------. 1 user1 user1 475 Jun 18 14:11 /opt/tester/etc/test.properties
```

(my java class is running as root and there are no symbolic links on the path)

any ideas why this is happening?
Thank you.

**UPDATE:** just created a file 'test' on the same directory added a word inside with 'nano' and still doesn't work.. so I guess the file is okay and is something else

**UPDATE 2:** going on my books as unresolved.. I think it has something to do with the path I set it with / and it's stored as \ when look on the debugger. But runs fine when is not ran trough the debugger. So that, I think is caused by my environment (code running on Linux being remotely debugged by Mule Studio 1.0.0 (based on eclipse 3.6.1) running on Windows 7).

**UPDATE 3:** read something saying that maybe 32 bit debugger on VM and 64 bit debugger in client might have something to do with the glitches.. so I moved everything to my local machine and now is debugging fine.

Comment: `testFile` == `secretsFile` ?

Comment: `testFile` created, then `secretsFile.exists()` ... ?

Comment: The umask could be the problem here. What's the root's umask? 0077? This would explain this. ... or I may have misunderstood the question :D

Comment: typo on my post, the code doesn't have that typo. sorry guys

Comment: not 077 (severe) it has 022 (Permissive)

Comment: can you check isAbsolute() and getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: ok - so this is something else. no idea at the moment. the actual umask that would cause this is 0077. fixed in my answer.

Comment: thanks, at least I'll know this for the future :)

Comment: Any chance that the real code has some other line between the `if` line and the `System.exit(0);` line? In which case, enclose your full `if` clause in `{}` braces.

Comment: nop, erased the only line of code that was in the middle and added braces.. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Stupid of my part, I'm debugging remotely!! so I think that eclipse is looking for the file on my system rather than on the remote machine. (first time using remote debugging)

(this is not the correct answer, as I just learned the remote debugging should not interfere at all with this)

Comment: don't know where to add the file on my windows box so I can continue debugging remotely..

Comment: I don't think it's that. If you are attaching to process on remote system, then it will look for file on the remote system.

Comment: Try changing the statement to a file that is actually on your windows machine, then you will know if this is the problem. You are not debugging remotely then

Comment: interesting, I don't really know how the remote debugging works just started using it, (boss just passed told me the same thing XD)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a bug caused by not enclosing your `if` condition in `{}` braces. In absence of braces, if there is any line between the `if` and the `System.exit(0)`, then the exit will always be invoked (as it is not part of the `if` clause).

Comment: only had one line in original code, the error was that I'm debugging remotely through eclipse and apparently it looks for the file on my local system while debugging

Answer (score 0):

I know that this may look childish, but still can you please try this code, as it worked for me...

To write the file on the disk:

```
try {
    File f = new File("path_of_file"); 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write("Hello");
    bw.close();
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code checks the Existence of the File in specified location:

```
File f = new File("path_of_file");
if(f.exists()){
    System.out.println("success");
}
else{
    System.out.println("fail");
}
```

Comment: interesting: I got the following exception on the first line of the second part of your code   java.io.FileNotFoundException: \testfile.txt (Access is denied)

Comment: check the path, have you given it correctly, and please once again double check the permissions. please

Comment: I'm going for the most simple path now: "/usr/testfile.txt" about to test... oh and ls -l :drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root  4096 Jun 22 13:01 usr

Comment: you know something wonky.. (im step debugging and after the file creation) I check the directory and the new file is not there, it wasn't created

Comment: 1st you should have some respect and consideration for the people who invest time in your code, that you can NOT figure out... so next think twice before you say someone wonky!!! and I got my code totally working.. either your permissions are not in place, or you are messing it up.. If i get sometime, i will also post the eclipse output i got

Comment: noo you are not wonky!! I'm sorry I meant the behavior of my code is wonky! not you, not anyone!

Comment: Try this code on Windows OS, if you see, i am sure u will, see this code working flawlessly, then i think you will be satisfied with the working correctness of this code.. And yes, please select any drive except "c:" cause again you may fall into the security trap if you are using Windows 7 and u have not set the security properly.

Comment: yes code is working perfectly in Widnows.. my problem is somthing with linux or its permissions. something weird is that my forward slashes are becoming backward slashes.. i don't know why this is happening

Comment: try giving path like "//usr//testfile.txt"

Comment: now got this "java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\usr\testfile.txt (The network path was not found)"

Comment: no :( I entered File f = new File("/usr//testfile.txt"); (note the forward slashes and I got an exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: \usr\testfile.txt with the backslashes! a path that linux would not recognize!

Comment: SO if I run the program (no debugging) your code works.. but if I turn on debugging it doesn't work (it doesn't create a file).. how could this be?

Answer (score 0):

You stated in a comment that it works perfectly on windows. This is clearly a user privilege error.
Try this command in a terminal emulator

```
sudo chmod 777 /path_to_file
```

More about the command [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

It'll bypass any user-access privilege errors.

Afterwards, try running `Kumar Vivek Mitra`'s code again.